Would Linode and AWS S3 be sufficient to launch a mobile application?
I am building a mobile application using React Native and SpringBoot for a client. This application will handle usual content delivery, however will also allow users to watch videos saved on our cloud storage. The videos need to be behind paywall. So far, after considering bandwidth, computing and storage costs, I have suggested the client to proceed with Linode as it is not as expensive, and although it is not as elastic, the client is not expecting the application to have excesive growth. I have also sugested AWS S3 for the video storage for ease of use and security, even though Google Cloud and Azure are nominaly cheaper.
With this said, my client is sceptical that this is the best provider combination and has aksed to reach out to ask for suggestions from the community. So considering...

Java SpringBoot backend (with MySQL)
React Native (Expo) frontend
React Js (for admin content control)
Videos in mp4 and mov formats

What would you suggest the best provider is?
